# Neutralino.window.setDraggableRegion is malfunctioning on windows

Tags: neutralinojs

What happens is that I initiate the window drag instruction with Neutralino.window.setDraggableRegion, it works but there is a very big problem in rendering.
I am on a windows system. Here is a video of the problem:
[Video of the problem](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-52epDK1ycKDsrFY-wtqt21-gpUIrC2J/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: There was no [Rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendering_(computer_graphics)) issue in the video, can you explain what is the problem?

Comment: I explained it also here https://github.com/neutralinojs/neutralinojs/issues/820

Comment: But there too, you haven't explained what sort of rendering issue, since it looks normal.

Comment: observe the position of the cursor relative to the draggable area. The draggable area is colored blue. When I move the window using this area, the cursor leaves the blue area.

Answer (score 0):

As you specified, the window is dragging but the mouse doesn't move with the point you click on, instead the mouse is at a different position.

I Looked at how draggable region function works under the hood, and it's handled by the JavaScript Client File, by setting the window position to the amount of mouse has moved on x and y.

since the mouse pointer doesn't move instead the window moves relative to the position from where you started clicking.

I will raise this issue, and soon a fix for this will be out!

[Issue has been raised](https://github.com/neutralinojs/neutralinojs/issues/837)